# Android snackbar swipe bug

Tags: android-snackbar, snackbar

In my Android app I have a snackbar. When it is on the screen, I try to swipe it out, but after swiping another layout on the screen isn't changing. So, it looks like it presents on the screen with visibility setted to View.INVISIBLE. Is there a bug or am I doing wrong something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is a Bug in Support Library 23.2.0. This problem presents in Google Keep app for Android. It's shown on the screenshot.[image: Snackbar swipe bug in Google Keep app]